# svn checkout is not working with php exec()

Tags: php, svn, tortoisesvn, svn-checkout

I want to checkout some files from svn to my locale folder using php. For that I write this code.

```
    $checkout = "svn --username myuname--password mypass checkout svn://192.16.20.125/projname/trunk/content/Poems/files.swf  D:/PHP_Projects/MyTempRelease/content/Poems/files.swf";    
    exec($checkout);
```

But its not checkout file to my locale. Not return any error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd try this with a client - Tortoise or something else.  Just to see if it works.

I'd also wonder if the lack of a space between "myuname" and "--password" is killing you.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you are missing a space between your username and --password.

Try running the command directly (on the command line) and verify that it is working.